# MagicalRecord and dispatch_group

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord and in one of my view controllers the data source is feed with data coming vom a database. As the feeding process includes multiple steps I tried to use GCD to speed up the whole process.
The general process looks like so.

The work to be done after fetching accessing properties in globalSummary.
The problem is that the app hangs at dispatch_group_wait. I tried to add work to the step and it works at the beginning but as I add more work it works if I go step by step through the code but doesn't work if I let it run.

Is something wrong with the approach or does it conflict with MagicalRecord in some way?

```c
- (NSArray *)dataSource
{
    if (_dataSource == nil) {

    _dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [NSManagedObjectContext contextWithStoreCoordinator:[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator defaultStoreCoordinator]];

    GlobalSummary *globalSummary = [GlobalSummary insertInManagedObjectContext:privateContext]; // holds a bunch of fetched properties

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("de.berndrabe.dataSource", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_group_t outerGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    __block SectionInfo *siPilotAircraft = nil;
    if ([PilotAircraft countOfEntities]) {
        dispatch_group_async(outerGroup, queue, ^{
            NSArray *frPilotAircraft = [PilotAircraft findAll];
            // do some processing an set SectionInfo variable
        });
    }

    __block SectionInfo *siMedicals = nil;

    if ([PilotMedical countOfEntities]) {
        dispatch_group_async(outerGroup, queue, ^{
            NSArray *frPilotMedical = [PilotMedical findAll];
        });
    }

    // more working packets following the same patter

    dispatch_group_wait(outerGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    if (siPilotAircraft.countOfRows) {
        [_dataSource addObject:siPilotAircraft];
    }
    if (siMedicals.countOfRows) {
        [_dataSource addObject:siMedicals];
    }
}

return _dataSource;
}
```

EDIT:
  Using `[Entity findAllInContext:privateContext]` lets fetches the record I need, but it still now I got stuck when accessing a faulty relationship in one entity :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem.
Here again (in short) what I tried to accomplish.

Task
build an `NSMutableArray` which will act as the dataSource object for a `UITableView`
each entry includes core data fetch and processing operations
parallelise work and add results on completion, make sure access to the `NSMutableArray` is regulated
start working with the dataSource object on completion

Problems
the number of entries in the dataSource object can vary

Here's was worked for me.
The category on 'NSMutableArray' is a convenience method to make sure the access is serialized.
With that implementation you have parallelised the work as much as possible and you can savely
write

[self prepareDataSource];
[self.tableView reloadData];

without worrying that some work is still in progress.

```c
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourdomain.serializedAccess", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

- (void)prepareDataSource
{
    [self.dataSource removeAllObjects];

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    [self prepareWorkEntry1FromManagedObjectContext:self.privateContext forDataSource:self.dataSource group:group];
    [self prepareWorkEntry2FromManagedObjectContext:self.privateContext forDataSource:self.dataSource group:group];
    [self prepareWorkEntry3FromManagedObjectContext:self.privateContext forDataSource:self.dataSource group:group];

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}

- (void)prepareWorkEntry1FromManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context forDataSource:(NSMutableArray *)array group:(dispatch_group_t)group
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [context performBlock:^{
    Object *object = nil;
        createObject(object);

    if (object) {
           [array serializedAddObject:object withQueue:weakSelf.queue group:group];
        }
        else {
          dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }
    }];
}


@implementation NSMutableArray (ResourceProtection)

- (void)serializedAddObject:(id)object withQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue group:(dispatch_group_t)group
{
    if (group == NULL) {
        dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
            [self addObject:object];
        });
    } else {
        dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
            [self addObject:object];
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        });
    }
}

@end
```

EDIT:
As far as the ResourceProtection category is concerned you have to make sure

1. dispatch_group_enter is called before dispatch_group_leave
2. dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave are balanced

Here it is an observed, synchronized writer scheme for a mutable object.

Comment: Can you actually confirm that `performBlock:` will execute the given blocks in parallel with respect to other blocks? I fear, they run serialized. Also, a minor improvement would be to make `prepareDataSource:` asynchronous, having a completion block which gets invoked when all asynchronous tasks (performBlock:) are complete. dispatch_group_wait unnecessarily causes the calling thread to block until after all tasks have been completed.

Comment: As Apple states in its documentation it is an asynchronous call, so it returns immediately. Nevertheless it enqueues the block to its private queue and (I guess)will do its best to get the jobs done a fast as possible. But as this might include database access of some sort it might be serialized. For the last point you mentioned (group_wait ...) this was I wanted to achieve. I needed the dataSource object completely configured before I start using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose another approach which uses a helper library which makes asynchronous tasks much easier to implement: it uses "Promises" as a means to signal the completion (or failure) of an asynchronous tasks.

Basically, instead of a completion block, an asynchronous tasks (method in this case) looks as follows:

```
- (RXPromise*) doSomethingAsync;
```

The *eventual result*  respectively a failure can be obtained via handlers which will be "registered" like shown below:

```
- (void) foo 
{
   RXPromise* promise = [self doSomethingAsync];
   promise.then( <completion handler block>, <error handler block> );
}
```

or shorter, and with the handler placeholders filled with actual code:

```
- (void) foo 
{
    [self doSomethingAsync]
    .then(^id(id result) 
    {
        // result is the eventual result of the asynchronous task
        return nil; // return the result of the handler

    }, id(NSError*error)
    {
         NSLog(@"ERROR: %@, error"); // the task failed with error
         return nil;
    });
}
```

Note: the handlers itself execute on a private thread (actual a concurrent dispatch queue).
In order to synchronize shared access within handlers one can explicitly specify the dispatch queue where the handler will be executed:

```
- (void) foo 
{
    [self doSomethingAsync]
    .thenOn(dispatch_get_main_queue()), ^id(id result) 
    {
        // Here, we are executing on the main thread
        // result is the eventual result of the asynchronous task
        return nil; // return the result of the handler

    }, id(NSError*error)
    {
        // Here, we are executing on the main thread
         NSLog(@"ERROR: %@, error"); // the task failed with error
         return nil;
    });
}
```

Note that the asynchronous tasks executed in `[self doSomethingAsync]` may be executed on its own private thread (or queue).

"Continuation" of more than one asynchronous tasks can be easily accomplished:

```
task1()
.then(^id(id result1{
    return task2(result1);
}, nil)
.then(^id(id result2) {
    return task3(result2);
}, nil)
.then(nil, ^id(NSError*error)
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong in task1 or task2 or task3: %@", error);
    return nil;
);
```

After this short introduction you can solve your problem as follows:

Define your asynchronous tasks, which return a RXPromise:

```
- (RXPromise*) prepareWorkEntry1FromManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
- (RXPromise*) prepareWorkEntry2FromManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
- (RXPromise*) prepareWorkEntry3FromManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;


- (RXPromise*) prepareWorkEntry1FromManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    RXPromise* promise = [RXPromise new];
    [context performBlock:^{
        Object *object = nil;
        createObject(object);

        if (object) {
           // success
           [promise fulfillWithValue:object];
        }
        else {
           // failure 
           [promise rejectWithReason:@"object creation failed"];
        }
    }];

    return promise;
}
```

Likewise, implement the other tasks.

Combine the results in the handlers:

```
- (void) foo 
{
    [self prepareWorkEntry1FromManagedObjectContext:moc]
    .thenOn(self.sync_queue, (^id(id object)) {
        [self.dataSourceArray addObject:object];
        return @"Finished 1";
    }, nil);

    [self prepareWorkEntry2FromManagedObjectContext:moc]
    .thenOn(self.sync_queue, (^id(id object)) {
        [self.dataSourceArray addObject:object];
        return @"Finished 2";
    }, nil);

    [self prepareWorkEntry3FromManagedObjectContext:moc]
    .thenOn(self.sync_queue, (^id(id object)) {
        [self.dataSourceArray addObject:object];
        return @"Finished 3";
    }, nil);

}
```

Note that the `dataSourceArray` will be accessed in the dedicated `sync_queue`. This shall be a serial dispatch queue.

Note also, that method foo is effectively asynchronous.

There is also the possibility to "asynchronously wait" until a number of asynchronous tasks have been completed:

```
- (void) foo {

    NSArray* promises = @[

    [self prepareWorkEntry1FromManagedObjectContext:moc]
    .thenOn(self.sync_queue, (^id(id object)) {
        [self.dataSourceArray addObject:object];
        return @"Finished 1";
    }, nil),

    [self prepareWorkEntry2FromManagedObjectContext:moc]
    .thenOn(self.sync_queue, (^id(id object)) {
        [self.dataSourceArray addObject:object];
        return @"Finished 2";
    }, nil),

    [self prepareWorkEntry3FromManagedObjectContext:moc]
    .thenOn(self.sync_queue, (^id(id object)) {
        [self.dataSourceArray addObject:object];
        return @"Finished 3";
    }, nil)

    ];

    [RXPromise all:promises]
    .then(^id(id arrayOfPromises){
        // all tasks *and its handlers* finished.
        ...
        return nil;
    }, nil);
}
```

I'm the author of this library which you can find here: [RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise).

Comment: In your - (RXPromise *)prepare.. implementation performBlock is an asynchronous call so it would immediately return the newly created RXPromise object without having ever reached the fulFill or reject methods.

Comment: Yes, the promise itself will be immediately returned, but the result is available only after the promise has been fulfilled or rejected. This happens in the block, which is executed at arbitrary times after it has been passed to the context. Using promises the code looks like as if it is synchronous. ;)

Comment: Maybe a short description what happens here may be useful: when you invoke `foo` you queue three blocks - the "workload" for the context. `foo` immediately returns - it's async. Each of the workload will finish eventually, and a handler of the corresponding promise will be called which is executed on the sync_queue. Each handler will add the task's result to the `dataSourceArray`. The workloads may execute in parallel, but likely they will be executed serially by the context. This is irrelevant to the handlers, they are serialized on the sync_queue.